# Vector network analyzer for SMPS feedback loop measurements

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

Does there exist a ready-made design for implementing the measurement hardware? You can buy the analyzer package from e.g. Omicron Lab but it's a hideously expensive piece of kit (4490€) considering what you're actually buying. Never mind Ridley's version at $17.5k.

It's possible to measure a SMPS circuit feedback loop bode plot by injecting a signal into the loop and measuring the response. Theoretically you can do this with a signal generator, transformer and 2-channel oscilloscope. In practice it's not that simple - to start with, finding the right transformer to do your testing between, say, 10Hz and 1MHz. Has anyone managed to do that in a reasonable way using "homebrewed" equipment?

Like so:
[image: circuit diagram]

Basically what that very very expensive equipment does for you is to generate and record the various test points which is a tedious business at best.

Comment: I think Omicron's expense if I am not mistaken on your model is the high voltage used to test large transformers 1mHz to 1MHz with constant V/F and the analysis software.  I recall a cheaper Bode plotter but you can get use a step response at different current steps to gain the same insight.  But yes we once did it with bench sig gen synced to sweep on a SA for 14" HDA servo response loops. and I have many times used FM with scope X sweep out to get a filter envelope response as long as blanking interval was greater than filter latency

Comment: not the same as I thought.  This Omicron has over 7 decade sweep options with 1Hz to 50MHz and 1Hz to 5kHz variable tracking filter.  That is no joke to make and is probably a UHFdown converter. with DSP

Comment: Impedance-converting transformers are used to inject test signals into low-impedance nets as power rails. You don't need the transformer to inject signals into high-impedance feedback network.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I'm sure it's very good for the job it makes but to start with that's excessive bandwith to get the job done. Most feedback loops would go below unity in single or double digit kHz unless you did something wrong. 10Hz to 1MHz would be enough for most purposes. Another niggling issue is the interaction between current and voltage loops plus slope compensation, this is usually hand-waved away. I saw a Texas datasheet mentioning this recently, citing it's "tedious" process to do the math the hard way but actually explained how.

Comment: @Ale..chenski In every single diagram I've seen for gain-phase response there's a transformer involved so I'd presume it needs to be there. If for no other reason, how are you going to inject current with correct DC bias ?

Answer (score 5):

Maxim has a good app note on winding your own isolation transformer for this application: [Maxim app note](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3245)

It's not very easy to make these kinds of measurements with a signal generator and scope.  The network analyzers have narrow moving digital filters that allow comparison of the gain and phase of the output signal vs. the input signal in the presence of noise and harmonics.

I have access to these types of analyzers at work, but for my home lab I was able to find an old HP 3562A on Ebay for $400.00.  It works fine for loops with crossover up to 100kHz.

You might also try an old gain/phase meter like the HP 3575A, which you might find even cheaper, but I'm not sure how good the results would be.

If you want to get ambitious you could get a signal acquisition board for a PC and write a bunch of code to do it yourself.  Would be a fun but tough project.

Comment: In the not quite DC to ~90KHz region, this sounds like a job for a PC soundcard.... Indeed I have used such for the purpose of plotting G/B curves for sonar transducers. The two channels are nice as you can trivially sample the signal at the point you are injecting the test signal to calibrate out amplitude and phase errors while sampling the output voltage with the other channel. If faster is wanted you can build simple quadrature mixers around bus switches to allow measurement in 90KHz bands at at least into the HF bands.

Comment: You can even analyze the log response on Audio with very high sampling rates using free Audacity and a Turtle Beach Audio card or maybe a good USB module??

Comment: todays best price on HP3562A is less than the model number but $2600 used

Comment: 100kHz is a bit low, You may not see the gain margin.. But for the price I guess it's not bad.

Comment: HP3577A looks pretty promising with the 5Hz to 200MHz band. You can get it from Ebay for $750 delivered to UK. It can handle 25VDC input. Combine that with the Maxim appnote on wiring the Pulse Electronics transformer secondary you should have decent feedback loop analyzer on a budget.

Comment: @Barleyman I agree, 100kHz is a bit low for modern buck converters, some of them have pretty high bandwidths.  Still I find it works for about 80% of what I work on, and I have access to much better analyzers at work.  The HP3577A does look promising, it might be a better way to go than the 3562A.

Comment: Our RF guy doesn't like the idea of using network analyzer to measure feedback with the Vripple present but here's a thread in EEVblog about using 3577A to measure SMPS circuit so it should get the job done: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/dynamic-load-bode-plot-using-hp-35665a-dsa/

Comment: I'd love to have access to a proper network analyzer for work, but I've never been able to justify why I need a 3.5k€ instrument which is going to be used a couple of times a year. So I'll do the feedback loop modelling as well as I can and observe how's the base stability on various loads and temperatures and tweak step response as appropriate. Texas gives you tons of info on the modelling part while someone like Linear gives nothing at all - You have to talk to their FAE and they justify it that it'd "confuse" engineers if they had access to detailed info.

Answer (score 3):

You can even analyze the log response on Audio with very high sampling rates using free Audacity and a Turtle Beach Audio card or maybe a good USB module.

There are technical reasons with higher order loops**, **why Bode Plots are not useful and hide unstable regions** and Nyquist plots must be used in the frequency domain or Step response.

**e.g. saturation heating and many ESR*C time constants.

### [How to make a scope into a Network Analyzer](http://www.effectivebits.net/2011/12/how-to-make-oscilloscope-into-network.html)

### **HOWEVER,  I would rely on Step Load Voltage response to measure SMPS stability and noise using AC couple into a 50 Ohm load**

You could use Fourier transform with log amplitude and phase of repetitive pulse step loads. using PC and Audacity. with channel, calibration to correct for phase shift on audio AUX input channel or get a better sound card.

**But you need a tracking filter to eliminate the SMPS noise and aliasing effects.**.

This would require using variable repetitive step pulse, from I1 to I2 to find the worst case THD or harmonic content or Vpp result.

Often overshoot from high current to zero current with lots of ringing occurs that demands some dynamic load to maintain current feedback stability or extremely well-designed RLC reactance for high current SMPS.  Loop gain often changes with load and *mu* with temperature.

Comment: +1 for step load voltage response advice.

Comment: Yes, step response is the old cop-out you sometimes see in datasheets since you can actually measure that with an oscilloscope. I don't really see why it'd be better than bode plot since it would be similarly affected by operating parameters. And step response won't help you much to figure out where the problem actually is if your supply is not stable. Step response is an useful parameter to measure for an SMPS of course.

Comment: @Barleyman if you research higher order effects, you find it is good only if highly 2nd order and no nearby higher order poles or zeros ? near RHP, so OA’s ok, SMPS, not so OK so not cop out but the acid test, BODE is still useful but not to measure actual stability margin from overshoot, ringing under worst case step loads

Comment: Nor for switching half bridge reactive loads but MUST be done with AC 50 Ohms

Comment: Data sheets are your “gold” standard for test methods, not a cop out.

Comment: I concur, all datasheets are created equal.

Comment: Yes, They are supposed to be created using the best practices for test methods and defining errors from specified conditions. i.e. the gold standard for Test and design Engineers to learn then improve when necessary for quirks like spurious resonance in setup. But the critical thing is the more Z's in parallel the higher the ordered network yet the best opportunity for a flat low Z but also worse case for anti-resonant spurs. so BODE cannot be used to indicate margins because of the lumped elements of ESR*C and ESL. and RH zeroes in Nyquist plot. ideally, an SMA connector for semi-rigid

Comment: .. coax to AC coupled 50 Ohm load for any high frequency high power DC-DC power supply. then very low ESL controlled step currents to measure the resulting error voltage.  A 500A DC busbar as I have modelled on this site, gets fairly complex for powering BLDC AC motors but can best be done my way as defined or even a 5A supply operating > 1MHz, its all depends on required accuracy of measurement. But for what you get in software analysis tools Omicron's price is good for some things.. Smith Charts etc.  So the homebrewed low ESL voltage controlled current sink active load is the best tool.

Comment: We used to pay much more for these transient Analyzers and programmable "Active Loads" to test power supplies in production, when I was Test Eng Mgr.

Comment: Designing high power LED backlight units (>1kW) you get your transient response test for free due to PWM dimming. I'm a fan of costant current mode for driving LEDs althought it has some caveats on local dimming.

Comment: @Barleyman I AGREE with CV using variable Feedback to Vfb ratio using current sense to adjustable SMPS voltage with no noise and span 0 ~100% power.